# Disable auto highlighting on focused view for Oreo device

Tags: android, focus, android-8.0-oreo

On new android device(Oreo - 8.0/Samsung S8) my view gets auto highlighted when focused. I need to disable that. Any ideas how to do that?

Answer (score 3):

I found myself:

```
<item name="android:defaultFocusHighlightEnabled">false</item>
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setDefaultFocusHighlightEnabled(boolean)